# Adding item to a Dropdown box (using CB_STRING), starting from char array

Tags: arrays, visual-c++, sendmessage, dropdownbox

I have been trying to populate a dropdown box using data from a char array

```
char state[100][100];
char states[100];
char *test[1];


//FILL ARRAYS
char state[0][0] = 't'  
states[1] = state[0][0]   
test[1] = "CALIFORNIA";


SendMessage(hwnd2,CB_ADDSTRING,0,(LPARAM) states[1]); //wont add db item
```

**HOWEVER, the following will fill the Dropdown BOX:**

```
SendMessage(hwnd2,CB_ADDSTRING,0,(LPARAM) test[1]); //db item added  WORKS
```

I'm using MSVS 2010.  My goal is to transfer from a ***2d array to a 1d array***, so that I can use CB_ADDSTRING to populate items in a DROPDOWN BOX.  Can someone please tell me what's going on?   Much appreciated.

Comment: These are pointers, you have to use `strcpy`, or you can initialize arrays with string literals. I suggest you study basic C/C++ before starting with WinAPI programming. Use C++ `std::string` class, or use a high level language like C#/.net to assign strings like that.

Comment: I should have elaborated.  I've already initialized all of the arrays in a different section of code.. I've updated my post to reflect this extra information.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a character array to string literal as follow:

```
char buf[] = "Text";
```

Or initialize 2-D char array, which is single array of strings:

```
char str_array[][10] = { "Text1", "Text2" };
```

Array index starts at zero. `str_array[0]` and `str_array[1]` are valid.

Use `strcpy` to copy strings.

```
char another[100][100];
strcpy(another[0], "array_0");
strcpy(another[1], "array_1");

SendMessageA(hwnd2, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)buf);
SendMessageA(hwnd2, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)str_array[0]);
SendMessageA(hwnd2, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)str_array[1]);
SendMessageA(hwnd2, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)another[0]);
SendMessageA(hwnd2, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)another[1]);
```